# Laravel queues, how come the queue is processed right away?

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I've setup queues with Laravel 5.1.

I perform the HTTP request (Post), this is routed to the respective controller.

Controller executes the following:

```
//try saving model
try{
    $lg = new User();
    $lg->fill($request);
    $lg->save();
}catch(QueryException $e){
    Log::error( $e->getCode());  

}

//creates Job instance
$job = new ProcessUser($lg);

//dispatching job
$queue_id = $this->dispatch($job);
```

also if I

```
dump($queue_id);
```

instead of having the Id key fo the queue I get back 0.

Everything works.....as expected on local dev env, with Homestead.

But on production where I have CentOS... 
I expected the job just to be queued. Instead seems like it 's processed right away. (I can never see the Job inserted in my queue)

On my server (CentOS 6) I installed supervisor.
And it is stopped:

```
 $ service supervisord status
 supervisord is stopped
```

And also... I hardly doubt It could work since I didn't configure it in

/etc/supervisor.conf

What am I missing?
How can I check out how's processed the queue?

I have never issued any artisan command like

```
$php artisan queue:*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry all,

I realised I didn't configured properly the .env file by setting

```
    QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

it was set to

```
    QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Didn't know that "sync" config would process right away the queue...